# Does Google Adsense work on decent websites anymore?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-ads, monetize

There are many websites which are stuffed with ads. People may click on ads incorporated within the free content.

However, for decent websites such as *StackExchange* where ads are placed outside of the main contents on the side, I doubt if there is considerable revenue through CPC.

Instead, reputable websites sell their advertisement space based on their reputations rather than leads. The ads on *StackExchange* are served by Google, but it is not AdSense (what is it, by the way?).

Is my observation correct or still reputable websites can earn decent revenue by CPC schemes on ads placed on the sidebar?

Comment: It has always the case that experimenting with different ad placements is one of the best ways to get more revenue when using AdSense.  It was more than 10 years ago that Google put out a heat map of effective places to try ads.  I think they have taken it down from their help center now, but some other sites still make it available like here: https://www.monetizemore.com/determining-best-position-ads/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you precisely proved me point. According to the heat map, the single ad on the right side of the present page is in the coldest spot to receive clicks. This means neither SE nor the advertiser cares about the leads through clicks. Therefore, the present page does not work for the CPC scheme of AdSense.

Comment: My personal experience is that you don't have to "stuff" a site with ads to do well with AdSense.  A single well-placed ad can work great.  Just don't expect it to be totally unobtrusive.  Unobtrusive is pretty antithetical to the purpose of advertising.  But this has always been true.  Your title says "anymore."  What are you thinking has changed?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller people got used to ads. They unconsciously/automatically ignore ads.

Comment: Unless the ads are relevant and well-targeted. Facebook has what I think is the best algorithm; I regularly click on the ads, because they reflect what I like. Search engine PPC ads don't perform nearly as well in this department.